can freetype-gl texture-atlas reference glyphs with different variable font axis parameters set?
I'm building an application in c++ which renders variable fonts and animates variable font axis parameters, also called design coordinates.
From reading through the freetype-gl source code, it seems the library supports to alter variable font characteristics e.g. texture_font_set_weight, but does not include this information when storing the rasterised glyphs in texture atlas, because the key of the glyph in texture-atlas is just the char-code of the glyph plus some extra information (outline + some other metrics).
I'm researching text rendering libraries for multiple days now and can't seem to find a variable font rendering example where axis parameters frequently change. The challenge are the large number of possible variations, which makes pre-generating all possible glyphs unfeasible. Using an LRU-Cache + Saving design-coordinates as part of the cache-key + managing multiple atlas textures if they run out of space, would be a good start. Would it be possible to use the freetype-gl texture-atlas in this way?
